# Android Kotlin Convert date with Extensions file

Tags: android, date, kotlin

I need to convert the date in the `String` format to **Thu. 23 Sept 2021.**, that comes from an Api.
Api sent many dates and I want all of them to be converted. (With Extensions File)
How to do it?

Comment: Use gson library ,it can covert most of(json API date) the date format to java date

Answer (score 0):

use `SimpleDateFormat`,

```
val date = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy").parse("31/11/2021");
```

This will produce an output that you desired.

ie, Thu Dec 31 00:00:00 IST 1998

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet as kotlin extension.

```
fun Date.convertDate(dateString:String) : String{
     val inFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy")
     var date: Date? = null
     try {
        date = inFormat.parse(dateString)
      } catch (e: ParseException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
      }
     val outFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd MM, YYYY")

    return outFormat.format(date)

}
```

[image]

Comment: published.text = model.publishedAt - publishedAt is String

Comment: How I will use this extension if my date(publishedAt) is String

Comment: Do add extension in any class and then call:
published.text=Date().convertDate(model.publishedAt) like this

Comment: Error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference

Comment: In the provided extension function we are not calling "java.util.Date.getTime()". Error is from somewhere else.

Comment: but it points exactly to the extension and to the Data ().convertDate (model.publishedAt)